# Why use MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_NOREPLY?

Tags: memcached

I am writing a library that wraps libmemcached.

I noticed that there is an interesting behaviour setting for memcached which says that I can indicate that I do not care about the results of my memcached commands...

It is known as MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_NOREPLY. Why would somebody want to use this?

It would be great if someone could point out a few use cases? multi-get / multi-set spring to mind, but I am not clear how this would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASCII protocol noreply was a mistake.  Don't use it.

Binary protocol noreply can be used to make [really awesome optimizations](http://dustin.github.com/2009/09/23/spymemcached-optimizations.html) without any loss of correctness.

Comment: Thanks for the great blog post Dustin! I just posted another question here... Wonder if you could chime in on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260829/maximum-size-of-key-and-value-for-memcached-binary-protocol-user

Comment: Unfortunately, that requires a deeper knowledge of libmemcached than I've got.